# Is there a functionality in spring security to auto remove token from db once expiry time of that token is completed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, access-token, remove-if

I have implemented below code for spring security.
I am using spring version 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with security oauth-2 version 2.3.0.RELEASE
Is It possible to remove / revoke granted access token once its expiry time is completed? If so which class/method should be place and where, to achieve the goal ?

AuthenticationService.java

```
package com.oauth.config;
import java.util.Arrays;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import com.oauth.model.UserInfo;
import com.oauth.service.UserService;

@Service("authenticationService")
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (
                (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

            System.out.println("userId: " + request.getParameter("userId"));

            UserInfo user = null;
        try {
            user = userService.getUserInfoByUserName(username);
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
            return new User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user id or password.");
        }       
    }
}
```

Outh2Configuration.java

```
package com.oauth.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore;

@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        /*
         * @Autowired private CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;
         */

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests().and()

            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            //.and().logout().logoutUrl("/oauth/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/noAuth/**","/customerNoAuth/**" ,"/oauth/token").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling();
        }
    }



 @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter implements EnvironmentAware {

        private static final String PROP_CLIENTID = "client";
        private static final String PROP_SECRET = "secret";
        private static final int PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("myAuthenticationManager")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                //.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenServices(tokenServices());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            String secretEncoded = passwordEncoder().encode(PROP_SECRET);

            clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(PROP_CLIENTID)
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .authorities("ADMIN", "USER")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")                    
                .secret(secretEncoded)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);

        }

        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnvironment(Environment arg0) {
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            CustomTokenService defaultTokenServices = new CustomTokenService();
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.oauth.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticateService;

    @Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/noAuth/**",
                "/customerNoAuth/**",
                "/state/**",
                "/country/**",
                "/violation/**",
                "/ticketViolation/**",
                "/api/zipcode/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
        .userDetailsService(authenticateService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

CustomTokenService.java

```
package com.oauth.config;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import lombok.Synchronized;

public class CustomTokenService extends DefaultTokenServices {

    private final Logger log = LogManager.getFormatterLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Synchronized
    public OAuth2AccessToken createAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = null;

                try{
                    accessToken = super.createAccessToken(authentication);
                }catch(DuplicateKeyException e){
                    do{
                        log.info("===========DuplicateKeyException===========");
                        log.info(String.format("Duplicate user found for %s",authentication.getUserAuthentication().getPrincipal()));
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        try {
                            return accessToken = super.createAccessToken(authentication);
                        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e2) {
                            ++count;
                            log.error("Attempt count " + count);
                        }
                    }while(count<=5);
                }
            return accessToken;
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info(String.format("Exception while creating access token %s",ex));
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

CustomLogoutSuccessHandler.java

```
package com.oauth.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Spring Security logout handler
 */
//@Component
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    private static final String BEARER_AUTHENTICATION = "bearer ";
    private static final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "authorization";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);

        if (token != null && token.startsWith(BEARER_AUTHENTICATION)) {

            String accessToken = token.substring(token.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(accessToken);

            if (oAuth2AccessToken != null) {
                tokenStore.removeAccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
            }
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store tokens in ur DB.If anyone can access ur db ,he can easily get access to every data.Again if u want to store then i think u can make a scheduler to delete token.